# is there an applicationContext equivalent in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

I am developing a nodejs express web app.
I need to have a global object accessible from anywhere in the application.

is there an implemented applicationContext-like in express nodejs, or I have to implement it myself?

example :

```
const userID = AppContext.get("userID");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global object and assign variables to that object. This will make it accessible from anywhere in the nodejs process.

```
global.userID = data;
```

Comment: I am looking for something scalable, and recommended.

Comment: Are you sure you need a global variable? They are very rarely used.

Comment: in a web context u  need a global variable, for example: active users;